# How can I use a web.config with a VS2015 RC WebApplication?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I tried adding the web.config to the wwwroot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This worked before in VS2013 but in VS2015 with the web.config in that location it no longer recognizes .json file extensions. So I assume it no longer recognizes the web.config.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add `<remove fileExtension=".json" />`